# background-image: auto 100%; and responsive content inside it

Tags: html, css

I want to create a `div` with background image and fit his height to 100%. I can achieve it with `background-image: auto 100%;`, but how to place the text above the image in this case?

Please check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fgv7s5Lv/) (try to increase the width of the window with the result to understand what I mean).

P.S. The solution should be responsive.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
body > .container {
  background-image: url('https://paulmason.name/media/demos/full-screen-background-image/background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="container">
   text
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: **a)** you should reset `margin` on `body`. **b)** `background:cover` might be a better choice while clipping image if needed  **c)** `background-position` takes vertical position first, then horizontal value. You could update position to clip at best your bg : https://jsfiddle.net/fgv7s5Lv/1/ Just my own humble opinion :)

Comment: Thanks, but I need the 100% height of the image always (in all resolutions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could keep the container at least within the ratio of the `background-image` setting a `max-width`.

`100vh` equals the window's height

image is 1600px wide for 1100px of `height`. `width`'s ratio from `height` is average 1.44 (1600/1100).

At the most, if the container is `144vh` width (140% of height) content will stand hover the background filling up the entire container:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
                margin:0;/* reset */
 }
body > .container {
 background-image: url('https://paulmason.name/media/demos/full-screen-background-image/background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center top;
 background-size: auto 100%;
               max-width:144vh;/* update*/
  margin:auto;
  border:solid;;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
  text
  </div>
```

Other approach would be to clip the image as i commented earlier (let's keep here the elephant at middle and in sight):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  /* rset */
}

body>.container {
  background-image: url('https://paulmason.name/media/demos/full-screen-background-image/background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* update*/
  background-position: 100% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  /* end update */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Make the background-size:100%. You will get the responsive background-image with text**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
body > .container {
 background-image: url('https://paulmason.name/media/demos/full-screen-background-image/background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center top;
 background-size: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="container">
  text
  </div>
</body>
```